# I need help to code and use the android camera

Tags: android, button, menu, camera

I want to creat an application that allows allergic people to take picture their reaction when they have some allergic reaction, as well as the food they ate. Then they can add information to the documents, and save all of that, plus the geolocalisation. (the idea is that an allergic person needs a diary becauses usually he can see his allergologue once every 6 months )

I have written this code that works : I have to hit the menu button of the phone so that i can use the camera. But, I want now to have a button that allows me to use the cam. Can anybody helps me by changing my code and helping me to add correctly a button allowind the use of the camera so that i can take a picture with my android phone?

Faithfully,

my code:

package android.camera;

```
        import android.app.Activity;
        import android.content.Intent;
        import android.graphics.Bitmap;
        import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.provider.MediaStore;
        import android.view.Menu;
        import android.view.MenuInflater;
        import android.view.MenuItem;
        import android.widget.ImageView;



        public class CameraActivity extends Activity {

            private static final int PICTURE_RESULT = 9;

            private Bitmap mPicture;
            private ImageView mView;

            public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
                super.onCreate(icicle);
                setContentView(R.layout.main);

                mView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.view);
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
                MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
                inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
                switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.camera:
                    Intent camera = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                    CameraActivity.this.startActivityForResult(camera, PICTURE_RESULT);
                    return true;
                default:
                    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
                }
            }

    /*      public void onDestroy() {
                super.onDestroy();
                if (mPicture != null) {  
                    mPicture.recycle();
                }
            }*/

            @Override
            protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
                super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

                // if results comes from the camera activity
                if (requestCode == PICTURE_RESULT) {

                    // if a picture was taken
                    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                        // Free the data of the last picture
                        if(mPicture != null)
                            mPicture.recycle();

                        // Get the picture taken by the user
                        mPicture = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");

                        // Avoid IllegalStateException with Immutable bitmap 
                        Bitmap pic = mPicture.copy(mPicture.getConfig(), true);
                        mPicture.recycle();
                        mPicture = pic; 

                        // Show the picture
                        mView.setImageBitmap(mPicture);

                        // if user canceled from the camera activity
                    } else if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {

                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are asking...

In your layout file (main.xml) add a button:

```
<Button android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:text="Take Picture" android:id="@+id/take_picture"></Button>
```

Then in your onCreate Method:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
            super.onCreate(icicle);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);

            mView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.view);
            mTakePictureButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.take_picture);
            mTakePictureButton.setClickable(true);
            mTakePictureButton.setOnClickListener(new View.onClickListener(){

                    @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent camera = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                startActivityForResult(camera, PICTURE_RESULT);

        }
            });
        }
```

Comment: Yes ! thats great ! thank you and this is working ! but am wondering where the pictures are saved? I hope I can have a same document where I can save the user's comments, the pictures, and the geolocalisation. Should I save the data in a file? or in a local database that I manage with Sqlite? Can anybody help me please? (I maybe have forgetten to day that I am a beginner, but i like to code ^^)

Comment: I believe you need to save the picture. I am not sure if it gets saved. You can run this code and then check your gallery to see if the picture has been saved. For saving user's comments, pictures, etc you should manage an sqlite database. You can see an example here: http://adblogcat.com/sqlite-database/

Comment: thanks for the example. But I still have a question, is it possible to have the picture's users in the same local database? Can I use a file to save the user's data? please help me

Comment: I would create a folder in the Sd card and have the pictures there. You don't want to use the limited memory in the /data/ directory (where your sqlite should reside) to store images.